# Error : The result binding name must be set to zero for full result set and XML results

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

I have only a single row that is being returned from a sql query(`count(*)`), but upon execution of the package, it shows me the above error and package is failing.

I have the result type to "single row", and have mapped the output of the query(`select count(*) as 'result' from abc.tbl_nm`) to a variable of type Int32.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When mapping your 'Result Set', set your 'Result Name' to '0' and 'Variable Name' to the variable you are using.

Comment: That was not the least bit obvious. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Bit more info https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62605b63-d43b-49e8-a863-e154011e6109(v=sql.110)